# How do I filter through a nested array with multiple criteria?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been racking my brain on how to filter through an array with multiple criteria. I kept looking online, but there was always at least one factor that made the solution not work for my array and use case.

I have a large nested array that I need to filter down by two criteria:

Criteria 1: if there **are no** duplicates in the client name elements (`testArray[i][1]`) **then** add keep in array

Criteria 2: if there **are** duplicates in the client name elements (`testArray[i][1]`) **and** those duplicates do not have duplicate product codes (`testArray[i][2]`) **then** keep all records with the same client name elements, but only keep the first records with unique product codes (`testArray[i][2]`).

Here is a sample array so I don't give out client info:

```
let testArray = [
  ["ASDF245", "Jeff Hill", "BOP"],
  ["ASCG285", "Jerry F Tate", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF240", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF291", "Jake Sab", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF301", "Mary Stein", "WC"],
  ["ASDF460", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "WC"]
];
```

I have tried using nested for loops, filter functions, foreach functions, etc. I can always get them to get through the first criteria, but not the second. This is one of my latest attempts:

```
  let newArray = [];
  for (let b = 0; b < testArray.length; b++) {
    newArray.push(["s","s","s"]);
  }
  let count = 0;
  let tempArrayOne = [];
  let tempArrayTwo = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < testArray.length; j++) {
      if (testArray[i][1] == testArray[j][1]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count == 1) {
      newArray.push(testArray[i])
    }
    if (count > 1) {
      Logger.log(testArray[i][1]);
      tempArrayOne = testArray.filter((iTwo, jTwo) => {
        if (iTwo[1] == testArray[i][1]) {
          return iTwo[jTwo];
        }
      })
      Logger.log(tempArrayOne)
      //Logger.log(tempArrayTwo.findIndex((item) => {return item[1] == tempArrayOne[0][1]}));
      //Logger.log(tempArrayTwo);
      if (tempArrayTwo.findIndex((item) => {return item[1] == tempArrayOne[0][1]}) == -1.0) {
        //for(let s = 0; s < tempArrayOne)
        newArray = [...newArray, ...tempArrayOne];
        tempArrayTwo = [...tempArrayTwo, ...tempArrayOne];
      }
    }
    count = 0;
    Logger.log(newArray);
  }
  newArray.splice(0, testArray.length);
  Logger.log(newArray);
```

I feel super dumb because I think I am just overthinking the solution. For some reason, the filter function works on the first duplicate ("Jeff Hill"), but it doesn't work on the second duplicate ("Hello Dup"). For "Hello Dup" it just makes `tempArrayOne` an empty array, thus making the whole function pull an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects in JavaScript are your friend when it comes to removing duplicates. All you need to do is come up with the right key -- in your case the name and the product.

```js
let testArray = [
  ["ASDF245", "Jeff Hill", "BOP"],
  ["ASCG285", "Jerry F Tate", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF240", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF291", "Jake Sab", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF301", "Mary Stein", "WC"],
  ["ASDF460", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "WC"]
];

const dict = {};
testArray.forEach(([id, name, product]) => 
  dict[`${name}-${product}`] ||= [id, name, product]);
  
console.log(Object.values(dict));
```

Comment: Hey Christian, thank you. That totally worked, however, I wasn't able to use ||=, because the Google app script doesn't recognize it as an operator. The assignment operator seems to do the job alone. I assume it still works because it replaces the existing object if there is a duplicate, instead of ignoring it or creating a new one. But, do you think I will run into any problems using the assignment operator only with a big data set, instead of the ||=?

Comment: You can use use `x = x || newval` as a replacement of `x ||= newval`. The only issue with not using it is that it will use the last found value for the duplicate, not the first one.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep unique `item[1]` in an object and their `item[2]` in a set:

```js
const set = {};
const result = testArray.filter(item => !set[item[1]]?.has(item[2]) && (set[item[1]] ??= new Set).add(item[2]));
result.forEach(item =>console.log(...item));
```

```html
<script>
let testArray = [
  ["ASDF245", "Jeff Hill", "BOP"],
  ["ASCG285", "Jerry F Tate", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF240", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF291", "Jake Sab", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF301", "Mary Stein", "WC"],
  ["ASDF460", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "WC"]
];
</script>
```

```
` Chrome/117
------------------------------------------------------
Alexander   1.0x  |  x1000000  776  778  783  801  802
Christian   6.1x  |   x100000  470  476  477  478  478
------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let testArray = [
  ["ASDF245", "Jeff Hill", "BOP"],
  ["ASCG285", "Jerry F Tate", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF240", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF291", "Jake Sab", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF301", "Mary Stein", "WC"],
  ["ASDF460", "Jeff Hill", "WC"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "WC"],
  ["ASDF245", "Jeff Hill", "BOP2"],
  ["ASCG285", "Jerry F Tate", "BOP2"],
  ["ASDF240", "Jeff Hill", "WC2"],
  ["ASDF291", "Jake Sab", "BOP2"],
  ["ASDF301", "Mary Stein", "WC2"],
  ["ASDF460", "Jeff Hill", "WC2"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP2"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP2"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "WC2"],
  ["ASDF245", "Jeff Hill", "BOP3"],
  ["ASCG285", "Jerry F Tate", "BOP3"],
  ["ASDF240", "Jeff Hill", "WC3"],
  ["ASDF291", "Jake Sab", "BOP3"],
  ["ASDF301", "Mary Stein", "WC3"],
  ["ASDF460", "Jeff Hill", "WC3"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP3"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP3"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "WC3"],
  ["ASDF245", "Jeff Hill", "BOP4"],
  ["ASCG285", "Jerry F Tate", "BOP4"],
  ["ASDF240", "Jeff Hill", "WC4"],
  ["ASDF291", "Jake Sab", "BOP4"],
  ["ASDF301", "Mary Stein", "WC4"],
  ["ASDF460", "Jeff Hill", "WC4"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP4"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "BOP4"],
  ["ASDF245", "Hello Dup", "WC4"]
];

// @benchmark Christian
const dict = {};
testArray.forEach(([id, name, product]) => 
  dict[name + '-' + product] ||= [id, name, product]);
Object.values(dict);

// @benchmark Alexander
const set = {};
testArray.filter(item => !set[item[1]]?.has(item[2]) && (set[item[1]] ??= new Set).add(item[2]));
 
/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```

Comment: Thank you, Alexander, for offering another solution. It really helps open my mind to new ideas.